# Fiddlercore certificate bypass

Tags: android, fiddler, fiddlercore

How do i obtain the fiddler core certificate?

I have tried using Fiddler4 certificate and exporting it to desktop and installing it into the android emulator.

But I always end up with this certificate error. I am using fiddler core with android emulator to stimulate my app testing. I am just doing a small demo to see if it works. However, apparently, the certificate exported from fiddler does not seem to be valid.

[image: enter code here]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the bytes:

```
    internal static byte[] getRootCertBytes()
    {
        X509Certificate2 oRoot = Fiddler.CertMaker.GetRootCertificate();
        if (null == oRoot)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return oRoot.Export(X509ContentType.Cert);
    }
```

You can store them to disk using `File.WriteAllBytes()`.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry but what do i do with the storing the bytes to disk? Saving the file with an extension of Root.cer i suppose?